# python 3, pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and I need to create a new column and assign values. if say there are 100 rows in that column, I want to be able to say that the first 50 are assigned value 1 and the rest are 0. I know that in order to create a new column, I could do df['CLASS'] = 0, but in this case, all values are 0s. How should I modify this statement to be able to assign different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign values when you create the dataframe via a dictionary, as so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CLASS': [1]*50 + [0]*50})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3))
df['CLASS']=[1]*50 + [0]*50
```

Comment: What's np.random.rand(100,3) for?

Comment: Just to create some dummy data in the DataFrame